# In Logstash : Is there a way to create fields directly from the header of CSV files?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to know if logstash is able to create field name directly from the csv file, all I can find is the way to hardcode it like this:

```
csv {
            separator => ","
            columns => ["Timestamp",
                        "Imsi",
                        "imeitac",
                        "msisdn",
                        "mcc",
                        "mnc",
                        "rat",
                        "bearer",
                        "ID",
                        "Location"]
    }
```

However the fields may not come in the same order, so is there a more dynamic way to create the fields as it runs. Essentially I want to be able to create the all the fields according to the header of the csv file at the start of the parsing.

All resources I was able to find said it was not possible out of the box, if so what is another possible way to have this done?

Comment: Asking for a "best" answer is asking for an opinion. Avoid this problem by just asking for "other" answers and skipping opinions. Hope this helps.

Comment: (Edited) any other way will do, I am pretty new to ELK stack so I am just looking for new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

No so much, no. Logstash works on events, which are individual lines in a file in this case. By the time the CSV filter sees an event it has no idea what came before it.

To do what you're looking for, you will need a codec on the `file {}` input that ingested these vents. However, I can't find a codec do this. If you have the ability to change the format of the file, there is a `json {}` codec that *will* assign values to fields found in the file.